3D mapping of tight spaces with LiDAR, IMU and wheel odometry
are there any ROS2 packages that would excel in mapping tight spaces (tubes less than 2 meters in diameter?
I'm trying to map such space using Livox mid-360 lidar with biult-in IMU. My robot also provides wheel odometry (differential drive) but can't find any packages that are suited for that.
I've tried a lot of packages such as FAST-LIO, RtabMap, LOAM and LeGO-LOAM, but they all seem to either output nothing or get lost in a tight space.
All help is much appreciated

there are many packages for LiDAR odometry (lidar slam). You can try LIO-SAM since you tested other well known techniques.
Those packages requires 9-axis IMUs, since Livox buitin IMU provides 6-axis, it may not be a suitable option. See if you can work with external IMU such as xsens MTI series, I'm sure you'll have better results. Also, check the parameters settings from FAST-LIO, RtabMap, LOAM, LeGO-LOAM and LIO-SAM, it may improve accuracy in tight spaces.
